# The mean of exponential distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, summation, random-variables, convolution, exponential-distribution

I would like to ask the following question. Let's say we have two independent variables of x and y, and both are exponentially distributed with mean $\mu_1, \mu_2$. And let $S=x+y$. May I know whether the mean of S would be equal to $\mu_1+\mu_2$.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is generally true for any random variables you wish with finite means.

In other words, if $X,Y$ are random variables with $\mathbb{E}[X] < \infty$ and $\mathbb{E}[Y] < \infty$, then $\mathbb{E}[X+Y] = \mathbb{E}[X] + \mathbb{E}[Y]$.

In addition, $\mathbb{E}[cX] = c\mathbb{E}[X]$ for any constant $c \in \mathbb{R}$.

Together, these are known as the *linearity of the expected value*.

---

**UPDATE**

For your second question, to find the distribution of the sum, define $S = X+Y$.

Note that the event $\{X=x\}$ is a zero-probability event for any contintuous $X$ (but would be well defined for discrete $X$). To avoid this issue, define $E_x = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \{|X-x|<\epsilon\}$, which is a well-defined continuous analogy of $\{X=x\}$, with $\mathbb{P}[E_x] = f_X(x)$. Then
$$
\begin{split}
F_S(s)
 &= \mathbb{P}[S < s] \\
 &= \mathbb{P}[X+Y < s] \\
 &= \int_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{P}[X+Y < s|E_x]f_X(x) dx \\
 &= \int_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{P}[Y < s-x]f_X(x) dx \\
 &= \int_\mathbb{R} F_Y(s-x) f_X(x) dx,
\end{split}
$$
which you can now explicitly evaluate if you know the distributions of $X$ and $Y$.
You get a nicer identity when differentiating that to get the pdf on the LHS:
$$
f_S(s) = \int_\mathbb{R} f_Y(s-x) f_X(x) dx,
$$
so the pdf of the sum is a convolution of the elementary pdfs.

It should be easy to tell that this is *not* likely to be of the same form as $X,Y$ even if $X,Y$ are iid. (One famous exception is the normal distribution.)

In your specific case, 2 exponentials add up to a di-gamma function...

Comment: Thank you so much. Would you mind if I ask an additional question. So, if we want to know f(s), which is the probability density function of s, we might have to introduce the gamma distribution to do so, or f(s) is just equal to an exponential distribution with mean equal to the sum of $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$.

Comment: @HenryCai $\Gamma$ is your friend :) please see the update for in-details explanation

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, deeply appreciated.

Comment: @HenryCai you are welcome